# I need some assistance with Div Tags

Tags: html

for some reason I ended the div tag,but the text doesnt appear under the box:
http://codepen.io/refath1/pen/NPbKaB

```
</div>
So,we know everything
```

Comment: Why do you have your CSS in the HTML box?  Why are there `<body>` and `</head>` tags in there.  Try to clean up your example and maybe that'll fix it.

Comment: You should read up on how to structure an HTML document... Here's an example of a properly structured HTML 5 document : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/

Comment: Also, don't use `<font>` tags.  Use CSS.  Also, you seem to have forgotten most of your `</font>` tags.

Comment: Yeah,yeah,...............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's there but you forgot to close one of your `<font>` tags so it's just white:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxoOPx)

`<font color=white>` inside of `<div>` was never closed. It's a good habit to nest your HTML so you can see what's happening:

```
<div>
   <font color=white>
     A car is traveling at <i>x</i> mph.The car has traveled 
     <font color=yellow>
        <u>57 miles</u>
     </font> 
     over a time span of 
     <font color=lightblue>
        <u>9 Hours</u>
     </font>.
     What was the car's 
     <b>
       <font color=lightgreen>
         Average Speed? 
       </font>
     </b>
   </font> <-------THIS WAS MISSING
</div>

So,we know everything
```

Comment: @RefathBari Djave pointed out that it's white, but you need to read my answer to understand why it's white. You didn't close a tag.

Comment: I know that-Dont assume im a novice that doesnt know how to end font tags.

Comment: not to be rude but 1. I'm explaining *why* it was white, im not inferring you dont know how to close tags... 2. Why wouldn't I assume you're a novice considering your code structure and that you didnt think to check if the text was just invisible?

Answer (score 2):

The text is white on white so you can't see it.

Edit: Just, for the record, that is some of the worst html I have ever seen! Very '90s. I would recommend looking at some basic HTML tutorials – maybe on something like https://www.khanacademy.org/ or just Google HTML and CSS Tutorial

Comment: Thanks! Its appreciated.

Comment: Naa,no need.The only thing I care about is if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed tag.

```
<font color=lightgreen>
```

has not corresponding close tag.

By the way, you should not use `<font>` tags, as they've been deprecated.  It's better to use CSS for formatting.

Comment: You're right.  Closing that one makes the text visible though.

Answer (score 0):

a complete code when ever you open any tag it must end with `</>`

ERROR in your code is `<font color=lightgreen>` doesn't have close tag like `</font>`

try this

```
            <style>
            div {
                background-color: #FF9494;
                width: 300px;
                padding: 25px;
                border: 2px solid;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
                box-shadow-color:lightgreen;
                border-radius: 25px;
                border: 25px solid lightpink;
                margin: 25px;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><font color=lightgreen>An Introduction to </font><font color=lightblue>Physics</font></h1>
        <h2><font color=#FF9494><u>Speed</u></font></h2>To find the speed of a given object,we must know the distance it has traveled as well as the<i> t</i> time it took for the object to travel <i>d</i> distance.Lets apply what we know to this problem:
        <div><font color=white>A car is traveling at <i>x</i> mph.The car has traveled <font color=yellow><u>57 miles</u></font> over a time span of <font color=lightblue><u>9 Hours</u></font>.What was the car's <b><font color=lightgreen>Average Speed</font></b> ? </font></div>
        So,we know everything 
    </body>
```